# convergence of $\sum \frac {nx^{n-1}} {(1+x^n)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I want to examine the convergence of this function series $\sum \frac {nx^{n-1}} {(1+x^n)^2}$ for $x \in [2, +\infty)$. I showed pointwise convergence but I'm struggling with uniform convergence.

I tried to apply the Weierstrass M-test but it didn't work for me. I also tried to demonstrate that the series does not converge uniformly but that didn't work either. Does anybody have any hints?

Comment: I suppose that you noticed that this is the derivative of a much simpler summation. Is that helping ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici At some point I noticed that $\frac {nx^{n-1}} {(1+x^n)^2} \underset{n \to \infty}{\sim} \frac n {x^{n+1}} = (-x^{-n})'$ but I wasn't sure how to exploit this. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* $$\frac {nx^{n-1}} {(1+x^n)^2} \le \frac {nx^{n-1}}{x^{2n}} = \frac {n} {x^{n+1}} \le \frac {n} {2^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: We can use the ratio test to show that $\sum \frac n {2^{n+1}}$ converges (absolutely) and then use the Weierstrass M-test. Thank you.